# How to use PyQt4 with Python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, python-import

I need to import PyQt4.QtGui, PyQt4.QtCore and PyQt4.QtWebKit for my script.

since i couldnt find a 3.6 version of PyQt4, i used the latest PyQt4 release i got:

```
PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py3.4-Qt4.8.7-x64
```

When i tried to run my script it says

```
  from PyQt4.QtGui import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: module not found.
```

i tried several "solutions" and read everything i found, but until now nothing helped.

Can't PyQT4 (x64) be used under Win10 Home with Python 3.6 (x64) being installed?
Or did i miss something?

Comment: If you read carefully the name of your package: PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py**3.4**-Qt4.8.7-x64, you will notice that it is for version 3.4 of python

Comment: @eyllanesc that still doesn't mean it cannot work under Py3.6. it could just be the last Py version released the day they made 4.11.4, couldnt it? since im new to python i dont know when 3.4 was released. and if its not compatible, how to use scripts based on PyQt4?

Comment: The libraries like PyQt are in a certain way special, since they are converted from C ++ to Python, and to do it they are compiled and that depends on the python version, for example the PyQt dlls are going to look for the dlls with the appropriate version of Python . I recommend you to find the right pyqt package for your python version, or download the pyqt source code and compile it for your python version (this last task can be heavy), Another solution is that you use python 3.4

Comment: See this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt5/5.9.2

Comment: You can get unofficial pyqt4 wheels for python-3.6 [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4). Make sure you read [all of this info](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) before attempting to use them.

Comment: @eyllanesc i installed 5.9.2 and it seems as QtGui and QtCore are imported now. but they removed QtWebKit some releases ago: "With Qt 5.6 the following modules are no longer part of the release packages, but users can still build them from source:

    Qt WebKit" --- since im a bit overwhelmed..can u tell me how to build the missing WebKit from source? thanks for you patience